# How I can generate the unique ID in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, uniqueidentifier

I’m working with my graduation project in Laravel, and want to generate small unique ID "9 char max" ... I don't need UUID because this will generate 36 char which is too long.

Comment: Can you please add more information about what the issues you are experiencing are? You should add a part of your code that isn't working and the community can try and help you but Stack Overflow's purpose isn't to create solutions for you from scratch

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the PHP function like this:

```
function unique_code($limit)
{
  return substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, $limit);
}

echo unique_code(9);
```

The output looks like this:

```
s5s108dfc
```

Here are the specifications:

- base_convert – Convert a number between arbitrary bases.
- sha1 – Calculate the sha1 hash of a string.
- uniqid – Generate a
  unique ID.
- mt_rand – Generate a random value via the Mersenne Twister Random
  Number Generator.

Or in Laravel you can use laravel Str library:
just use this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
$uniqid = Str::random(9);
```

:::NOTE:::

While this function may produce unique codes for a certain period, it is not guaranteed to always generate unique codes. You should need to cross-check every time with existing codes in your system.

Comment: Does `Str::random` do anything to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: Are the strings really going to continue being unique even if I am just getting the substring?

Answer (score 6):

You can generate a random string with this library:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$id = Str::random(9);
```

Comment: where should I write this? and how I can deal with it in the database?

Comment: Could you tell me more about the purpose? So I think that I will be able to help better.

Comment: can you give me your email? or any account can I ask you through it

Comment: Does this do anything to ensure uniqueness?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this ,

```
$unique_id= echo floor(time()-999999999);
```

this is generating a 9 digit unique value based on time.

Answer (score 0):

Generate custom Unique ID or Code (With Prefix or Suffix Or Both Or Only Unique Id) Or reset your ID after the change of Prefix or Suffix Or Both in laravel framework

Visit https://github.com/SirajCse/laravel-unique-id-generator

Example:
Inv-000001/12/21

```
UniqueIdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'invoices','field'=>'invoice_id','length' => 16,'prefix' => 'Inv-', 'suffix' => date('/m/y')]);

'table' => 'invoices' [sting table name]
'field'=>'invoice_id' [Default 'id'] [Optional][any string field name]
'length' => 12 [Integer value Id length]
'prefix'=>'Inv-' [Default ''] [Optional] [any string]
'suffix'=>date('/m/y') [Default ''] [Optional][any string]
'reset_on_change'=>false[ Default false] [Optional] [Options are 1.prefix , 2.suffix 3.both 4.false]
uniqueId=000001
```

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 0):

Generate random string

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

dd(Str::random(9));
```

or generate sequence random number based on condition

```
function generateSequenceNumber($tablename, array $conditions = [], string $prefix, int $length = 5): string
{
    $model = \DB::table($tablename);

    if (is_array($conditions) && count($conditions) > 0) {
        $model = $model->where($conditions);
    }

    return $prefix . str_pad(
            ($model->count()) + 1,
            $length,
            '0',
            STR_PAD_LEFT
        );
}


generateSequenceNumber('tablename',[],'prefix-',5); //prefix-00001
generateSequenceNumber('users',['role' => 'admin'],'admin-',5); //admin-00005
generateSequenceNumber('users',['is_active' => 1,'role' => 'client'],'client-',8);
 //client-00000008
```